# python list.iteritems replacement

Tags: python, list

I've got a list in which some items shall be moved into a separate list (by a comparator function). Those elements are pure dicts. The question is how should I iterate over such list.

When iterating the simplest way, `for element in mylist`, then I don't know the index of the element. There's no `.iteritems()` methods for lists, which could be useful here. So I've tried to use `for index in range(len(mylist)):`, which [1] seems over-complicated as for python and [2] does not satisfy me, since `range(len())` is calculated once in the beginning and if I remove an element from the list during iteration, I'll get `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Finally, my question is - how should I iterate over a python list, to be able to remove elements from the list (using a comparator function and put them in another list)?

Comment: So, you want to end up with the original list missing a number of elements, and a new list containing those elements removed?

Comment: @RicardoCárdenes exactly

Comment: FYI use .items() in Python 3.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a new list really isn't much of a problem compared to removing items from the old one. Similarly, iterating twice is a very minor performance hit, probably swamped by other factors. Unless you have a very good reason to do otherwise, backed by profiling your code, I'd recommend iterating twice and building two new lists:

```
from itertools import ifilter, ifilterfalse

l1 = list(ifilter(condition, l))
l2 = list(ifilterfalse(condition, l))
```

You can slice-assign the contents of one of the new lists into the original if you want:

```
l[:] = l1
```

If you're absolutely sure you want a 1-pass solution, and you're absolutely sure you want to modify the original list in place instead of creating a copy, the following avoids quadratic performance hits from `pop`ping from the middle of a list:

```
j = 0
l2 = []
for i in range(len(l)):
    if condition(l[i]):
        l[j] = l[i]
        j += 1
    else:
        l2.append(l[i])
del l[j:]
```

We move each element of the list directly to its final position without wasting time shifting elements that don't really need to be shifted. We could use `for item in l` if we wanted, and it'd probably be a bit faster, but when the algorithm involves modifying the thing we're iterating over, I prefer the explicit index.

Answer (score 2):

You can use enumerate function and make a temporary copy of the list:

```
for i, value in enumerate(old_list[:]):
   # i == index
   # value == dictionary
   # you can safely remove from old_list because we are iterating over copy
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer not to touch the original list and do as @Martol1ni, but one way to do it in place and not be affected by the removal of elements would be to iterate backwards:

```
for i in reversed(range(len()):
    # do the filtering...
```

That will affect only the indices of elements that you have tested/removed already

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried this yet but.. i'll give it a quick shot:

```
new_list = [old.pop(i) for i, x in reversed(list(enumerate(old))) if comparator(x)]
```

Comment: Leaving for 10 mins, will be back soon

Comment: `reversed` works on sequences only (which an `enumerate` object is not)

Comment: Use `reversed(list(enumerate(old)))` and you're good to go. Awesome solution +1.

Comment: Note that lists don't `pop` very efficiently, and so this is likely to create a lot of new lists behind the scenes.  Unless the list is very long, this may not be an issue in practice, of course.

Comment: @RicardoCárdenes Ah yeah i do notice. It depends on the python version you're using though, and the OP didn't mention it.

Comment: @DSM Thanks for the note! Completely agree, i wouldn't recommend such solution for longer lists. Things are much more difficult when they're big..

Comment: Bleh. Hidden quadratic complexity is not a good trade for iterating over the input once.

Comment: @user2357112 I loled. I realized that's very true. I think Ricardo's solution is better in that sense :))

Answer (score 1):

Try the filter command, and you can override the original list with it too if you don't need it.

```
def cmp(i): #Comparator function returning a boolean for a given item
    ...

# mylist is the initial list
mylist = filter(cmp, mylist)
```

mylist is now a generator of suitable items. You can use `list(mylist)` if you need to use it more than once.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, might be one line too much though.

```
new_list1 = [x for x in old_list if your_comparator(x)]
new_list2 = [x for x in old_list if x not in new_list1]
```

Comment: You're creating two new lists and you iterate twice. I'm looking for a solution to iterate once and move elements into another list (e.g. `l2.append(l1.pop(ind))`)

Comment: I'm simply gonna refer to @alKids solution. It doesn't get much cleaner.